# Creating a shortcut in windows forms vb.net Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, button

I have a button on my project that when you click, does something. Does anyone know a way that I can make it run the same actions as if you clicked the button (Without copying and pasting the code from the button) when you click something on your keyboard?

Comment: No need to copy code, just place this `myButton.PerformClick` at any EventArgs sub procedures you want.

Comment: What you'd usually do is have the code in a separate method and call that from the button click event. Then you can easily call it from elsewhere too without the button being involved.

Comment: Hello, Im sure this would solve it, its just that I'm relatively new to Visual Studio. Also, what I am trying to do is have the button's events run when I click enter.

Answer (score 0):

To set the shortcut to Alt+M (or m)

```
Button1.Text = "&My Button"
```

You can do this at design time by just setting the text property of the button with an ampersand preceding the letter you want to use for Alt +